# Managing users in openshift

Tags: dockerfile, openshift, ubuntu-18.04, sudo, sudoers

I am new to openshift, I have deployed an image using Dockerfile on it, using ubuntu as base image. In Dockerfile, I have assigned an user with root privileges. But after container is formed, my user gets overidden by some random user. Because of which I am facing permission denied error on creating and reading files and directories. How can I stop this random user from overriding the user mentioned in my dockerfile or how can I assign root privileges to the random user. I tried using sudo but got below error:

```
sudo: PERM_SUDOERS: setresuid(-1, 1, -1): Operation not permitted sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting sudo: setresuid() [0, 0, 0] -> [1005180000, -1, -1]: Operation not permitted sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Below is the entry I made in my Dockerfile for user:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install sudo
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ubuntu && usermod -aG sudo ubuntu
RUN echo "ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >>  /etc/sudoers

# Set as default user
USER ubuntu
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

In OpenShift the userid is, by default, taken from the namespace annotation.  It looks random, but is deterministic.

In general, you solve this by using *GROUP* 0 membership on files.  The user your container runs as by default has the high uid, and also gid=0.

For a "container native" application you wouldn't expect to make use of sudo.  If you really need this, for example a forklift move of a virtual host into a container, then look at the OpenShift SCC and allow something like "anyuid" which in turn will allow a securityContext with runAsUser: 0.

Comment: hey @dbaker thanks for replying.. So if I want my user to create directory and execute files at any path.. I need to allow security context with runAsUser: 0 ??

Comment: Yes, but there are two stages.  First your container (or pod) needs the runAsUser if this is needed to override the default USER in the container image itself.  Second the service account (or user) deploying the pod needs permission on an SCC that will permit it (such as the "anyuid" scc).